# Update on INNER JOIN not working

Tags: sql, sql-update, inner-join, amazon-redshift

I am trying to update a table in Redshift from another table by using inner join.

Query:

```
UPDATE target 
INNER JOIN updates ON target.name = updates.name and target.title = updates.title and target.age = updates.age 
  SET target.num_hit_ratio = updates.num_hit_ratio, target.plan_id = updates.plan_id;
```

This is giving error:

> syntax error at or near "INNER"

Where am I making mistake?

Comment: This is a redshift query based on postgres

Comment: There is no `inner join` in an update statement. See [the manual](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UPDATE.html) for details

Comment: You're probably looking for "update from" syntax. Update target set target.x=xyz.x from source x where target.id=x.target_id etc.

Comment: As mentioned above, this is covered in the docs. Eg. `UPDATE target SET ... FROM updates WHERE target.name = updates.name and target.title = updates.title and target.age = updates.age`

Comment: Yes. UPDATE does not support INNER Join. Thanks it worked

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the Redshift [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UPDATE.html), an UPDATE can join to other tables to generate the values in the SET command, but the join syntax is in the form of WHERE clause predicates (not explicit JOIN syntax).

```
UPDATE target
  SET target.num_hit_ratio = updates.num_hit_ratio,
      target.plan_id = updates.plan_id
FROM updates 
WHERE target.name = updates.name 
AND target.title = updates.title 
AND target.age = updates.age
```

Note this alternative WHERE clause syntax, by removing the AND keywords and wrapping the conditions in brackets:

```
...
WHERE
  (target.name, target.title, target.age)
  =
  (updates.name, updates.title, updates.age)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aliases too, that way your joins are more
readable:

```
UPDATE t
SET ...
FROM target t 
INNER JOIN updates u ON t.name = u.name AND t.title = u.title AND t.age = u.age
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your query, you would just need to rearrange a few things as follows:

```
UPDATE
    target
SET
    target.num_hit_ratio = updates.num_hit_ratio, target.plan_id = updates.plan_id
FROM
    target
    JOIN updates ON target.name = updates.name AND target.title = updates.title AND target.age = updates.age
```

Personally I would give your tables an alias, to make it easier to type (because I'm lazy :P):

```
UPDATE
    T
SET
    num_hit_ratio = U.num_hit_ratio,
    plan_id = U.plan_id
FROM
    target T
    JOIN updates U ON T.name = U.name AND T.title = U.title AND T.age = U.age
```